# Limit of $\prod_{i=1}^{k} i^{2^{-(i-1)}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Consider the expression
$$
P_n=\sqrt{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{4\sqrt{\ldots \sqrt{n}}}}}, n \ge 2.
$$
I was trying to show that $P_n<3,\, \forall n \ge 2$ (it's an old Putnam contest question) via induction, but I think the more interesting question is if we can find a closed form expression for the actual limit. Numerically, it seems that the answer is $2.7612...$.

Define the sequence $a_n=n^{2^{-(n-1)}}, n\ge 2$. Hence $a_2=2^{1/2}=\sqrt{2},a_3 = 3^{1/4}=\sqrt{\sqrt{3}}$ and so on. Clearly, $a_n$ is decreasing and approaches $1$ in the limit. It seems that
$$
P_n = \prod_{k=2}^n k^{2^{-(k-1)}} = \prod_{k=2}^n a_k \stackrel{?}{=} P_{n-1}a_n
$$
How should one take it further from here to obtain $\lim_{n\to \infty} P_n$?

Comment: This is the square of [Somos' quadratic recurrence constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somos'_quadratic_recurrence_constant).

Answer (score 3):

Let $P_k$ be the product in question.  Then

$$\log{P_k} = \sum_{i=1}^k  \frac{\log{i}}{2^{i-1}} $$

The sum converges as $k\to\infty$, but not to a familiar constant.

I can prove the inequality by first observing that the sequence $\log{P_k}$ and hence, $P_k$, increases monotonically.  Therefore $\log{P_k}$ is bounded by the limit as $k\to\infty$ for all $k$.

Also note that log is a concave function; therefore, the sum satisfies [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) as follows:

$$\log{P_k} = \sum_{i=1}^k  \frac{\log{i}}{2^{i-1}} = \sum_{i=2}^k  \frac{\log{i}}{2^{i-1}} \le \log{\left [\sum_{i=2}^k  \frac{i}{2^{i-1}} \right ]} = \log{3} $$

Therefore $P_k \le 3$.

Comment: If $Li_n(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k/k^n$ denotes the polylogarithm function, and $M(n,z) = \frac{\partial}{\partial n} Li_n(z)$, then $\lim_{k\to\infty} \log P_k = -2M(0,\frac12)$. That's sort of a closed form...

Comment: @GregMartin: I never said there was no closed form, I just said it wasn't in terms of a familiar constant.  I meant, $\pi$, $e$, $\gamma$, and the like.

Comment: That's more or less what I ended up with in proving the "$<3$" part; I was hoping that the limit is some constant that may have popped out in other kind of similar problems.

Comment: The question is about how to obtain the limit, as opposed to simply showing <3.

Comment: @CalvinLin: I did answer the OP in telling him that the limit had, as far as I know, no well-known constants.  The whole inequality thing was just an aside.